# How should I set a HttpURLConnection to be the same as a HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, http, servlets, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I have a server, and I want to forward the requests to an other server (maybe with modifications).

I use HttpURLConnection to connect to the second server (from the first server).
I can get a lot of information from the HttpServletRequest, for example:

- getAttributeNames -> getAttribute
- getHeaderNames -> getHeader
- getParameterNames -> getParameter
- getQueryString
- getReader (for body)

But for the HttpURLConnection I can only setRequestProperty(key, value). I don't really know whats the different between Attributes, Headers, Paramteres.

**How should I set the HttpURLConnection to be the same as the HttpServletRequest?**

What information do I need to "copy" or "clone" a request?

Should I get all attributes, headers, parameters and querystrings from the Request and set all of them with setRequestProperty(key, value)?

Comment: Are you sure a reverse proxy wouldn't be more suitable to achieve this?

Comment: @mthmulders It's very similar to a reverse proxy, but I want to modify some calls. Is it possible with a reverse proxy? How does a reverse proxy do this? (the getrequestdispatcher.forward is only good in the same servlet context as I know, and I want to forward to a different server)

Comment: Whether or not a reverse proxy would be suitable for you depends on what kind of modifications you want to do.

Comment: @mthmulders Most of the calls I don't want to modify, just forward it. But there are some calls, that needs to add or remove a header or modify the body. Or (like a makro) do a few calls, with the same credentials for example.
The reverse proxy is just a "method" not a concrete implementation I think. So what do you mean when you say reverse proxy? How should I implement?

Comment: Never mind, looking at what you want to do, I think a reverse proxy doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: You can use the Squid proxy, rather than a Java servlet, for this. See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation. And using ICAP, you can even write the content adaption code in Java.

Comment: @artbristol I have to use java servlets, but thank you for this information.